# Make SummaryLinkFieldControl Required

Tags: publishing-page

In MOSS I have created a new page content type with a new summarylinks field. I have added the field to my page layout. I set it as required in both the content type and in the site column. However it does not validate. I know I cannot edit this field in the edit properties view. When the page is in edit mode it still allows me to publish the page without adding an item to this field. Can I use jquery to validate this field? I am assuming that the reason SharePoint does not validate it is because of how this data is handled.

Comment: Does the column appear to be required when you look at it in the list settings?

Comment: The column is required when looking in the list settings as well as for the content type. It turns out this is no longer a requirement but it would be great if someone can figure this out for future reference.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently this is a known bug. It continued to occur in SharePoint 2010. The Feburary 2010 CU update for SharePoint 2010 fixes this problem for 2010. I have not taken a look at the 2007 CU's and Service Packs to determine if it was fixed with in those anywhere.